# Assets Upload Error

Tags: assets

I'm trying to upload own assets, but it occurs always the error that the file path "{assetsBasePath}/sites/" doesn't exist. Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: Got it, the BasePath was set in the wrong general.php

Comment: How many general.php files do you have ;)

Comment: I know Paul is joking, but he's kinda right... There are only 2 "general.php" files... the one in `craft/config`, and the one in `craft/app/etc/config/defaults`. You should really **never** modify anything in the `craft/app` folder, so the obvious choice is to modify your `craft/config/general.php` file.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, there's no environmentVariable `assetsBasePath` in your `config/general.php`. Without it, Craft can not replace the `{assetsBasePath}` part of the url by the correct path.

So, `config/general.php` should look something like this:

```
return array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => 'http://www.yourdomain.com/assets/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'assetsUrl' => 'http://www.yourdomain.com/assets/',
        'assetsBasePath' => '/path/to/your/public/folder/assets/',
    ),
);
```